# Problem making custom voice control commands

Tags: accessibility, voice

I want to make an app voice control on MacOs Monterey. I have enabled voice commands. I have created my custom command and set it to press a key.

Generally, voice control works. I can switch between dictation mode and command mode using my voice.

When in dictation mode, it will not recognize my custom commands, instead dictating them. When in command mode, it will not recognize my custom commands, ignoring them. The words I speak are recognized. They are visible over the microphone icon. I have checked the control to play a sound when it recognizes a command. The sound plays. It just doesn't trigger my custom commands.

In my application, I debug output all keyboard presses. I can see that the letters of the commands are typed if I am in dictation mode. So dictation mode works. My app gets the key presses.

Here is a sample custom command. You can see that it is enabled (of course).

[image: screenshot from custom command]